# How do i connect my electric guitar amp to my soundcard and use it as speaker?

Tags: audio, sound-card, music, amplification

I have a Focusrite scarlett solo g2 soundcard and a Laney 15watt LR20 amp. I use normal(not monitoring) speakers combined with a subwoofer and connect them to my soundcard and use Guitar Rig 5 app to play my guitar. Now I want to put away the speakers I have and use another pair of more professional ones. But I'm stuck between buying a pair of monitoring speakers like Mackie CR4 or using my amp as the speaker. I tried using a 6.3mm cable to connect my amp to my soundcard output without any other things in between. The presets that have delay effects on them, cause latency when using the amp. Now I've been told that in order to use my amp as a speaker in this setup I need to connect a preamp. And the preamps that I can buy in my country are more expensive than Mackie CR4 monitoring speakers.
Anyone who knows about this, please help me with this. If it needs more clarifying please inform me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this question is related to SU. You might want to try asking this on audiophile forum websites. Those guys could probably answer your question quickly. This doesn't seem like a computer related issue. But an issue with your amp.

Answer (score 0):

What would indicate how this setup will go is the purpose of it, meaning is it for practicing, live looping, recording etc...

First off your Focusrite is a preamp, a preamp takes a quiet, instrument level signal, and boosts it to a LINE level signal (higher than instrument.)

Your Focusrite Scarlett Solo will have a monitor output, this is the terminal in which you are connecting to a speaker and the one that will play post processed sound.  Make sure on guitar rig that the output is set to the Focusrite.

The processing that Guitar Rig and the Focusrite take time and there will be latency (lag) in the system.

Comment: Yeah it's all set to focusrite and sound is good. But when I connect it to the amp non of the presets are like when I play though my speakers. Maybe it's because the speakers are not monitoring speakers but normal ones.

Comment: output is output, the speakers you are plugging into don't change your guitar preset, I am honestly not really clear on your question... but make sure your output in the software is set to the focusrite.